# Where has Seq.apply gone in Scala 2.9.2?

Tags: scala

Scala 2.8.2 has a Seq.apply method, so that you can write the following in the REPL:

```
val l = Seq(1, 2)
l: Seq[In] = List(1, 2)
```

This still works in Scala 2.9.2, but what puzzles me is that according to the documentation, there is no such thing as a scala.collection.Seq.apply method anymore.

I checked with scala -Xprint:typer and this is what it prints:

```
[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: <console>
package $line14 {
  final object $read extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object $line14.$read = {
      $read.super.this();
      ()
    };
    final object $iw extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
      def this(): object $line14.$read.$iw = {
        $iw.super.this();
        ()
      };
      final object $iw extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
        def this(): object $line14.$read.$iw.$iw = {
          $iw.super.this();
          ()
        };
        private[this] val l: Seq[Int] = collection.this.Seq.apply[Int](1, 2);
        <stable> <accessor> def l: Seq[Int] = $iw.this.l
      }
    }
  }
}

[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: <console>
package $line14 {
  final object $eval extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object $line14.$eval = {
      $eval.super.this();
      ()
    };
    lazy private[this] var $result: Seq[Int] = {
      $eval.this.$print;
      $line14.$read.$iw.$iw.l
    };
    private[this] val $print: String = {
      $read.$iw.$iw;
      "l: Seq[Int] = ".+(scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.replStringOf($line14.$read.$iw.$iw.l, 1000))
    };
    <stable> <accessor> def $print: String = $eval.this.$print
  }
}

l: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

So the result is effectively:

```
collection.this.Seq.apply[Int](1, 2)
```

which indicates that it still calls Seq.apply, but where is this method?

Comment: This is a bug in ScalaDoc which is resolved in 2.10.

Comment: @sschaef: +1, it deserves to be a full-blown answer

Comment: I can't find the issue again -> not enough for an answer

Comment: A moment of fun: http://itmanagement.earthweb.com/img/2010/02/documentation-key.jpg

Comment: I believe I found the issue: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5558

Comment: @sschaef: Seems only remotely related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really a bug in Scaladoc 2.9.2.

I've inspected the scala-library.jar and found that the companion object scala.collection.Seq indirectly extends scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[Seq], which effectively provides the method signature:

```
def apply[A](elems: A*): Seq[A]
```

This in turn calls newBuilder, which is overridden in Seq to return:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Seq.newBuilder[A]
```